# Typeset: -A: invalid option error when trying to create an associate array in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to run a zsh script on version `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)` using `./filename`

```
typeset -A animals
animals=( ["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
echo ${animals[moo]}
```

But I keep getting the error that `typeset: -A: invalid option` It also throws the same error with  `declare -A animals`.  It works fine with a lowercase -a but thats not an associate array.

Comment: This example should work fine with zsh. What version are you using? How are you running this sample code?

Comment: I'm running it with ```./filename```

Comment: @jordanm version zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Comment: You had this tagged [tag:bash] as well, which suggests you are confused about the difference between the two. Are you sure you are using `zsh` to run the script? Does the file have a valid shebang line?

Comment: `typeset -A animals` is valid `bash`, as well. Unlike `bash`, though, if your script doesn't have a shebang like `#!/bin/zsh`, `zsh` will execute the script with `sh`, not `zsh`, and on macOS, `sh` is `bash` 3.2, which doesn't support `typeset -A`.

Comment: Either add `#!/bin/zsh` to the top of the script, or run it explicitly using `zsh filename`.

Comment: That was it.  I had ```#!/bin/bash``` at the top of my script.  Thank you very much